# zfs chown error - operation not permitted - checked ACL and still not working

Tags: zfs, acl, chown

zfs filesystem - try to `chown`, but fail...

```
root@tiny:/dancer# chown -R icetea:icetea

chown: changing ownership of './Taipei Space Ships/Disk2/private/SONY/SONY.MPG': Operation not permitted
```

try to check ACL

```
root@tiny:/dancer#getfacl './Taipei Space Ships/Disk2/private/SONY/SONY.MPG'

# file: './Taipei Space Ships/Disk2/private/SONY/SONY.MPG'
# owner: 501
# group: dialout
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

try to remove ACL

```
root@tiny:/dancer# setfacl -b -R './Taipei Space Ships/Disk2/private/SONY/SONY.MPG'
```

ACL hasn't changed...

```
root@tiny:/dancer# getfacl './Taipei Space Ships/Disk2/private/SONY/SONY.MPG'
# file: './Taipei Space Ships/Disk2/private/SONY/SONY.MPG'
# owner: 501
# group: dialout
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

still can't `chown`

```
root@tiny:/dancer# chown -R icetea:icetea

chown: changing ownership of './Taipei Space Ships/Disk2/private/SONY/SONY.MPG': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: What filesystem type is that? If it's a FAT or NTFS filesystem, these types don't cooperate with UNIX ownership.

Comment: it is ZFS, but the files probably came from NTFS

Comment: There's no ACL on that file, just the basic unix permissions reported by `getfacl`

Comment: What's the OS? If GNU-based, what's the output of `df -T './Taipei Space Ships/Disk2/private/SONY/SONY.MPG'`.

Comment: `root@tiny:/dancer# df -T './Taipei Space Ships/Disk2/private/SONY/SONYCARD.MPG'`
`Filesystem     Type  1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on`
`dancer       zfs  5249857408 4458436224 791421184  85% /dancer`

Comment: `getfacl` is the wrong tool to check ACLs on ZFS. `getfacl` only supports the ACL proposal from the early 1990s that never has become a standard. The historic ACL proposal was withdrawn in 1997. ZFS ACLs are usually checked via `ls -v` or `ls -V` if you are on a modern OS.